# How to concatenate strings when there is specific condition to meet in Dataframe Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am stuck with writing a Python function to concatenate names when specific condition is met.

| Names | Sequence text |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| y | 2 |
| a | 4 |
| b | 5 |
| c | 6 |

The desired output is below:

| Names | Sequence text |
| --- | --- |
| xy | 1,2 |
| abc | 4,5,6 |

The condition is that if the column 'Sequence text' has value increment of one, concatenate the names together as a single row.

Thanks so much in advance!

I am newbie in writing Python code, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) - df["Sequence text"])
    .agg({"Names": "".join, "Sequence text": lambda s: ",".join(map(str, s))})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  Names Sequence text
0   abc         4,5,6
1    xy           1,2
```

Comment: Doing the groupby by comparing to a running counter is brilliant.